Weird artifacts during Kubuntu 24.10 startup
I have a Lenovo Legion y740 gaming laptop. When I boot Kubuntu it shows the Lenovo booting animation as it should, but then it shows whatever the hell this is for about 10 seconds, and after this weird looking thing it starts up normally and shows the Kubuntu login screen. Is there a way to fix it?
I have Windows 11 and Kubuntu on one disk, and Windows 11 works absolutely perfectly.
Here’s how it looks.

Let me know if you need more information.
GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Max-Q
CPU: Intel Core I7-9750H
